# Setup Reverse DNS for a VPS host on a public network

Tags: bind, web-hosting, reverse-dns

Bassically, I'm trying to revive this question that got no correct answer: [reverse DNS (bind) for single ip/machine on non-private network](https://serverfault.com/questions/1097921/reverse-dns-bind-for-single-ip-machine-on-non-private-network)

So, I am trying to configure my own public DNS server for multiple websites hosting purposes.
My situation: I have a Contabo server VPS[Ubuntu 20.04, Bind9](which on I can manage my own rDNS records by myself for my VPS's IP address) and I'm on the stage where I want to configure the reverse dns for my ip, let's take `31.123.23.121` and `myhosting_domain.com`(which has `ns1-2 nameservers`) as my domain.
I have set on the Hoster Control Panel the domain name where I want my IP to point to(31.123.23.121 -> server.myhostingdomain.com), all that is remaining is set a proper reverse zone file(for bind9).
I fallowed this tutorial so far(-> https://tecadmin.net/configure-dns-server-on-ubuntu-linuxmint/), but I don't know how to convert the Reverse Zone File shown there to my case... .
Thank you very much!

(I'm still practicing, so expect newbie questions)

ALSO:
What I have tried is the configuration zone provided in the second answer of the question I mention, but obviously got errors:

```
$ORIGIN 121.23.123.31.in-addr.arpa.
$TTL 86400
@     IN     SOA    ns1.myhosting_domain.com.     staff.myhosting_domain.com. (
                    2001062501 ; serial
                    21600      ; refresh after 6 hours
                    3600       ; retry after 1 hour
                    604800     ; expire after 1 week
                    86400 )    ; minimum TTL of 1 day
# Update your DNS server
      IN     NS     ns1.myhosting_domain.com.
      IN     NS     ns2.myhosting_domain.com.

# PTR for 192.168.1.100 -> web.example.com
100    IN     PTR    server.myhosting_domain.com.
```

and got these errors on check:

```
root@vmiservername:/etc/bind# named-checkzone 31.123.23.121 db.121.23.123.31
db.121.23.123.31:3: ignoring out-of-zone data (121.23.123.31.in-addr.arpa)
db.121.23.123.31:9: ignoring out-of-zone data (#.121.23.123.31.in-addr.arpa)
db.121.23.123.31:9: unknown RR type 'Update'
db.121.23.123.31:13: ignoring out-of-zone data (#.121.23.123.31.in-addr.arpa)
dns_rdata_fromtext: db.121.23.123.31:13: near '192.168.1.100': extra input text
db.121.23.123.31:14: ignoring out-of-zone data (100.121.23.123.31.in-addr.arpa)
zone 31.123.23.121/IN: loading from master file db.121.23.123.31 failed: unknown class/type
zone 31.123.23.121/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

Comment: Did you also include the zone file in the `named.conf.local`? According to the examples the first line doesn't need to be there ($ORIGIN 121.23.123.31.in-addr.arpa)

Answer (score 1):

You can configure any DNS zone and record you want... it won't matter at all if the rightful owner of the upper level zone is not delegating that zone to you. This applies to reverse DNS zones, too.

In order for your answer to "what does 31.123.23.121 point to?" to be accepted by the rest of the world, the owner of the `31.123.23.in-addr.arpa` zone (or the most relevant sub-zone) must delegate the answer to you. If it doesn't, nobody will care at all about what you say.